# Rotated x-axis labels cut off in d3.js barchart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart in d3.js.  The text of the x-axis labels were too long and overlapping each other so I rotated the x-axis text by adding the following 4 attributes to x axis text:

```
      .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );
```

The problem is that the height of the space allocated to the x-axis labels did not expand so now I am only seeing the last few characters of the labels.  How can I expand the space allocated to the x-axis labels so that it extends to show all the rotated text?

Here's is the complete d3.js code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("segmentcount.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Count");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count); })
      .style('fill', function(d) { return '#' + d.colour } );
});
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Why dont you try horizontal bar chart, where your X and Y axes will be replaced. In fact, many visualization expert suggest using horizontal bar charts when you have long labels. If you still think that vertical bar chart is the one that you want to go with.. Could you please give the link to your dataset too? Then I can check if I can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the maximum label height, and translate the x axis accordingly.  (Because the labels are rotated we compare the label widths).

Code snippet to illustrate:

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

 var data = [
  {name: "long name", count: 20},
  {name: "name", count: 30},
  {name: "even longer name", count: 10},
  {name: "long name 4", count: 6},
  {name: "long name 5", count: 17},
  {name: "long name 6", count: 30},
  {name: "long name 7", count: 45}];

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
  return d.name;
 }));

 var gXAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(xAxis);
 gXAxis.selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

 // Find the maxLabel height, adjust the height accordingly and transform the x axis.
 var maxWidth = 0;
 gXAxis.selectAll("text").each(function () {
  var boxWidth = this.getBBox().width;
  if (boxWidth > maxWidth) maxWidth = boxWidth;
 });
 height = height - maxWidth;

 gXAxis.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

 var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
  return d.count;
 })]);

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Count");

 svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function (d) {
   return x(d.name);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function (d) {
   return y(d.count);
  })
  .attr("height", function (d) {
   return height - y(d.count);
  })
  .style('fill', "blue");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly!  I'm curious,  why did you have to move all the y-axis stuff, like var y =.....;   y.domain.... var yAxis to lower in the code to be contained with the d3.csv fuction while the x-axis defintion could stay up top?

Comment: @Snapula - the height of the y axis also changed to take into account the space used by the labels, and the range uses the new height.  I could have just moved down the line `y.range([height, 0]);`.